# Work with SQLITE database using visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, system.data.sqlite

I'm Trying to work with SQLITE database using visual studio 2013. I have installed [System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64) 1.0.92](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite) to visual studio. And installed the Setups for 64-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.5) as well.

**Problems**

---

1. It gives me and exception when i'm trying to create database using
   code first.

   > SQL logic error or missing database no such table: ****
2. Cannot create Entity Data Model using existing database. No provider
   is there to create connection. So Cannot Use Model First
3. Cannot Create data connection. There is no SQLITE provider. Cannot Use DB First within visual studio

**Success Scenario**

---

1. I can create SQLITE database manually(outside visual studio) and connect to the database
   and read/write/delete data using Entity Framework/ Manual coding.

Is there any way to overcome above problems.

Comment: I'd suggest SQL Compact which would work out of the box

Comment: @Alex: Visual Studio 2013 doesn't support SQL Compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity framework 6 for SQLITE is not supporting Database/ Table creation when you use code first.

You need to create database manually and create tables using `ExecuteSqlCommand`

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(filePath);
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(SqLiteQueries.CreateEnterpriseApplicationsTable);
```

OR as mentioned in the question Success Scenario, it support the code first with existing database.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is.

- Target .NET Framework 4.0 from project properties.
- Change what is in your App.config file with this (After the line that declares xml version);

<`configuration`>
  <`startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy ="true"`>
    <`suppurtedRuntime` version="v4.0"/>
  <`/`startup>
<`/configuration`> 
(I couldn't insert the XAML code here correctly so check before copying or type it manually)

-In case there is a problem with your connection string use;

```
  public static string ConnectionString = @"Data Source = databasename.db;Version=3; "
```

The last thing means that I suggest you to use SQLite3.

Comment: I thought these changes would help you to creat database "inside" your application considering you succes scenario. But let the answer stay and guide the people who has corresponding problem.